# 4 Dimension hough space

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform

I have a dataset of images that have been processed by some code that for each image, it generates `S x R` images.

Where S is the number of scales, and R is the number of aspect ratios. so for 3 scales and 3 aspect ratio. i have 9 images (each one is a hough space in the two parameters X and Y)

Now i want to write some code to get the peaks (local maximum) in that hough space, i have made some code using matlab and `vision.LocalMaximaFinder` which works only on 2 dimensions, but i feel that it is full of heuristics and not that robust.

So is there any available implementations (in any language) that could find the peaks on that 4D hough space ? or any resources on how to code such thing ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make sure that your images are stored in a XxYxSxR array "im". Then

```
[maxes maxi] = max(im(:))
[x,y,s,r]=ind2sub(size(im),maxi)
```

The problem here is that many max-values really close to each other. So I would suggest to run some Non Maximum Suppression on the 4D-image. A simple way is to sort the max values loop through the max-points (sorted) and kill off all "max-points" within a radius of the current one.

Comment: i will try that, but actually i was looking for an existing tested solution .. to avoid any incorrect heuristics i might be forced to make